# integrate C# UI (WPF) with flow chart

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Recently, I try to develop an UI by WPF.
As a requirement, I have to put some flowcharts on the form.
And I've already tried my best to find some open resource for my project.

for example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part

However, I have no idea how to integrate third party resource into my WPF project in VS2013 from very beginning at all.
(I know this sounds stupid...I'm totally new to this kind of development.)

My expectation is : to include whole third party resource into my project, so that I can drag some utility of them, double click on it and write some code
- just like how we usually do to default utility provided by VS2013 (say:button, textbox,treeview...etc.)

I hope there would be someone who can teach me how to do this, thank you.

Comment: If you have an assembly you want to use, just add it as a reference to your project. Did you do that? This is not really the type of question you should be asking here though. MSDN provides a comprehensive introduction to the use of the Visual Studio IDE and C# compiler settings. If you've read through all that and are still confused, then you can ask a question, but one which explains exactly what you've tried and what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake. I was so desperate to do so because I can't even find the instruction I need on MSDN. (I tried before I post the question thought.)

Comment: Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx. It's not very clear in your question what you're having trouble with, but it seems like maybe you just need to add the reference. That MSDN link will help you understand what that means and how to do it.